# Can I get the team id of a user using app store connect api?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Can I get the team_id for a user using app store connect api? I have looked https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/users but don't see anything. I don't necessarily need it for a specific user but the team id related to that particular app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Store Connect ID works via `issuer-id` and no longer exposes old / legacy identification like `team_id` or `portal_team_id` similar to how `fastlane` uses it via web authentication: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/48151291f2c4949c3b1b9919ba2cc81a7cc33293/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/spaceship.rb#L42

An ASC API key is only ever valid for one team, therefore in the API logic it should also not have access to that information.

Comment: Makes sense. My use case is that I have the APC API details for several teams so it would be nice to have a way know which team I am dealing with. Thank you for answering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning to find the `teamId` under which the API Key you are using is registered, of course you can. It will be available in the response of `GET v1/bundleIds` under`attributes` key :-

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "name": "app-name",
                "identifier": "com.organisation.app",
                "platform": "UNIVERSAL",
                "seedId": "team_Id"
            },
        }
}
```

The `seedId` under `attributes` will hold the `teamId` value.

Obviously, this solution assumes that the team has generated at least one bundle ID but since most teams should have done that this can be considered as a good approach to fetch `teamId` using App Store Connect API. For teams without any bundle ID generated, we might have to dig the App Store Connect API deeper to find out any other option.